# requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: python, sockets, udp, modbus, plc

I have a PLC and laptop connected to a network.
IP address of PLC is 10.101.133.13 and that of laptop is 10.101.133.14

I wanted to execute a simple socket program using python and the code is as follows:

```
import socket
ipaddr = "10.101.132.13"; port=3500;
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((ipaddr,port))
```

I'm getting an error
**[WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context** pointing to the s.bind() statement.

Please help me get rid of this.
There is already a program related to MODBUS running on PLC. I want to connect to the PLC through python socket programming.

Answer (score 0):

Binding can only be done to a local address. It looks like you try to bind to the address of a different system, i.e. the PLC. You probably meant to `connect` to the remote system instead.

Comment: I am not understanding what actually is meant by local device or remote device. I am new to these concepts. Please throw some light on what local device is and how that differs in connection perspective etc. 

BTW, how do I connect to the PLC in such cases. What settings in PLC do I have to change/modify for it to communicate with the laptop?

Comment: @RajeshV: local device is the laptop, i.e. the one which is trying to connecting to the PLC. You need to fix your program, not change anything on the PLC. It might be useful to understand the basic concepts of network programming, especially what bind and connect do.